# How to position li::before 'outside'

Tags: html, css

I want to align an li::before psuedo element as if I was doing a

> list-style-position: outside

```css
ul{
  width: 300px;
}

.cool-list li{
list-style: none;
}

.cool-list li:before{
content:"\2716";
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cool-list">
<li> item</li>
<li> One 'problem' with the Guardian's method <span style="background-color: yellow">is list items</span>  </li>
<li> Item </li>
<li> Item </li>
</ul>
```

I want to align the highlighted part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative margin can do this.

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
}

.cool-list li {
  list-style: none;
}

.cool-list li:before {
  content: "\2716";
  color: #000;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cool-list">
  <li> item</li>
  <li> One 'problem' with the Guardian's method <span style="background-color: yellow">is list items</span> </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `list-style` instead a pseudo and the pseuddo [`::marker`](https://css-tricks.com/style-list-markers-css/) to reset the color :

```css
ul{
  width: 300px;
}

.cool-list li{
list-style: "\2716\0020"; /* add a white space ? */
}

li::marker {
  color: crimson; /* give a different color to the list marker ? */ 
}
.cool-list li.good {
list-style:"\2714\0020";
}
li.good::marker {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<ul class="cool-list">
<li> item</li>
<li> One 'problem' with the Guardian's method <span style="background-color: yellow">is list items</span>  </li>
<li class="good"> Item </li>
<li> Item </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that Safari doesn't fully support this yet
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

Comment: @Cornel , but list-style does, the workaround for the marker is to set the color to li, then wrap the text into another tag (<a> tags are often found) like a span to reset color ;) Safari might loose the color, but it won' hurt and probably will not even be noticed by the visitor. take care. for the support you can look at https://caniuse.com/?search=marker ;) Supported by Safari 11.3 and above.